# Codeigniter when to create new controllers/models

Tags: codeigniter

I have watched many youtube guides/tutorials but those only tackle the coding part.

Whenever i start a project, i always start with a simple controller called main.
and 2 models.

For example: if i were to start an online store project. Then my models would be 'product_model' and 'user_model'. All database functions for users, i always put them in the 'user_model' and all database functions for products, i always put them in the 'product_model'.

**user_model:**

```
public function register(){

}

public function login(){

}

//more functions for user
```

**product_model:**

```
public function create_product(){

}

public function review_product(){

}

//more functions for product
```

My problem is that i easily get confused with my project and/or dissatisfied with how unorganized it is. especially when im more than halfway into the project and i accumulate hundreds of lines of codes.

I could try to organize them myself but at the end of the day, i'm just an amateur so i end up doubting myself. so i get no work done for 1 day(or doing work but redoing it again and again). then that snowballs to tomorrow and the day after that and so on and so forth.

So i want to ask to experienced programmers a basic guideline for me, when to create a new model and a new controller?

How do i group up functions and make them into a separate model?

Do i make a new model per table? and all database functions to that table i just write in the new model created for that table?

Or

Do i group up database functions based on what they do? for example: purchasing a product involves many separate database functions. so save them all inside purchase_model?

Comment: op, could it be that you're having trouble with wrapping your head around the logic rather than where to put your code?

Comment: I cant wrap my head around where to put my codes. 

When i am more than halfway through my project, i usually end up updating some functions. Also i don't have a proper plan going into my project so my functions in 1 model/controller are not written in chronological order( i just write them up as i go by so theyre a jumbled mess). I also use notepad++ so i end up using ctrl+f most of the time.

Comment: if you've some troubles with your code - or it feels that way - its often more useful to provide some examples... because most of the time its a design problem - even if you've an environment which provides `MVC`, but often this isn't enough....

Comment: Is there a way i can upload my entire codeigniter folder? Coz its very messy.

Atleast right now i have an idea on my models. but my controllers its a mess.

I'm used to doing just 1 controller for everything and idk how to divide that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to all of these questions is: **it depends**. Personally I think that kindof of flexibility is what makes coding so interesting.

As a general rule of thumb I try to keep all my classes less than 500-700 lines of code and functions less than 20 lines of code. If my class becomes larger than that I usually start a new one. With that being said, controllers I am fine with being larger as form validation and response logic can take up quite a few lines.

So let's take an example: **user authentication system**

I would have a controller that contains functions for login, registration, forgot password, and activation; another controller for user management that contains functions to delete, ban, unban, activate, and create new users; and then another controller for the users' profile that contains functions for editing their details and profile picture.

Now as user management and auth systems are typically reusable a library is better then using a model or models; but let's say we use models. I would have a model for each of the controllers outlined in the aforementioned paragraph and then a model for general "utility" functions like checking if the user is logged in .etc.

## Generally

You have to decide:

1. How much code is too much for a controller/model?
2. (with above) Do I expect my code to grow? If so then I have to take into account how much when determining (1).
3. How should I group together functions? For this keep in mind separation of concerns e.g. auth functions shouldn't be grouped with database backup functions.
4. Am I doing too much in a particular function/model? If so, how should I separate these items so that I conform with DRY principles (chances are some code is reusable elsewhere even though its functionality is inherently different).
5. (with above) If this code is really that useful elsewhere, should I make it into a library/helper?

(and there are countless other things to take into consideration).

I think it is important to realize (especially as a beginner) that your coding style and the "techniques" and organization skills you use will be constantly evolving and so will your code. While it is nice to see that you want to learn the best practices - a lot of this will be dependent on *what you want to achieve with your app* and what level of mastery you are at in your coding career. Try and look at the bigger picture and realize in a year or two when you look at your code again you will probably say "what was I even thinking here?".

Side note: you could research the ORM approach to models (Laravel and a host of other frameworks use it) but CI has a more "whatever" approach to just about everything. If being forced to work a certain way makes you feel more secure, you might want to learn other "more advanced" and "newer" frameworks.

Comment: So in essence, for now i shouldnt care so much and just try to make my project as appealing to me as possible that way i won't lose drive into completing it.

I'll check out the orm approach and possibly how other frameworks does their thing. Might give me ideas.